# AWS Boto3: See Permissions Required to Run Code Successfully

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, permissions, boto3, roles

Let's say I have a lambda function on AWS running some boto3 code. This boto3 code interacts with a variety of AWS resources, such as CloudWatch, S3, SNS, Lambda etc. In the execution role, I obviously may need to add certain permissions, such as lambda::CreateFunction as an example.

Now I want to add a permission policy to this function and add all the necessary permissions. Currently the only way to do this seems to be to run the code, read the error about it not having access to a certain permission, and then adding that permission to the permission policy. This can get very tedious and time consuming, especially when the code interacts with a large variety of different AWS resources.

So my question is, are there any ways to just see what permissions the boto3 code will require before running it? Maybe somebody has made a script for this before that reads through the code and prints out the permissions that would be necessary to run it?

Comment: There isn't any automated way to do that that I am aware of. Usually when people post some code like that on the Internet for reuse they include an IAM policy in the README that shows you the permissions that are required.

Comment: Not everybody is just reusing code from the internet when they create lambda functions but ok. Hopefully this is something that gets implemented in the future

Comment: Are you saying you are creating the Lambda function yourself, but you need help knowing what AWS permissions it needs?

Comment: Yes, the boto3 docs don't mention what roles are actually necessary to run a function. So outside of any obvious permissions, all I can do is run the code trial and error and then add permissions as their errors come up

Comment: Boto3 is a fairly low-level SDK on top of the AWS API. There should almost always be an exact 1-to-1 match with a boto3 method call and a specific IAM permission that you need to grant for that call. Can you give an example of a boto3 method that it is not obvious for?

Comment: Mostly IAM stuff that is easy to forget about. Just wanted to see if there was a tool out there to make the process faster

Answer (score -1):

If you build your services using the [AWS Cloud Development Kit (CDK)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/v2/guide/home.html), then you can simplify the process of granting your Lambda permissions to the correct services.

As a simple example, say you have a Lambda function and a DynamoDB table. You design the infrastructure in CDK with something like this:

```
const someTable = new dynamodb.Table(this, 'someTable', {
  tableName: 'someTable',
  billingMode: dynamodb.BillingMode.PAY_PER_REQUEST,
  partitionKey: {name: 'id', type: dynamodb.AttributeType.STRING},
});

const someLambdaFunction = new lambda.Function(this, 'someLambdaFunction', {
  functionName: 'someLambdaFunction',
  runtime: lambda.Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
  handler: 'index.handler',
  memorySize: 128,
  timeout: cdk.Duration.seconds(10),
  code: lambda.Code.fromAsset(path.join(__dirname, '../yourpath')),
});
```

And then you can grant permissions in one line:

```
someTable.grantFullAccess(someLambdaFunction);
```

CDK then generates the CloudFormation templates with the correct roles and permissions.

Comment: Is there a boto3 alternative to this? I can't use CDK in my case

Comment: That's just a shortcut for building the IAM role. It's not doing anything automatically. You still need to know that you need to grant full access to the DynamoDB table, which means you need to know what API calls the Lambda function's code is going to make. The question is about how to know what permissions need to be granted, your answer is just a shortcut for building the IAM policy once you know the permissions that need to be granted.